# phone camera calibration-opencv

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I 'am trying to calibrate my phone camera using the tutorial provided in OpenCV and the chessboard pictures but the code doesn't show the final result and I keep stumbling upon this error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-9dc3cfc36f25> in <module>
     33 
     34 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
---> 35 ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)

NameError: name 'gray' is not defined
```

This is the code that I ran

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((6*9,3), np.float64)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:9,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

images = glob.glob('*/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Homework/Homework_1/im.jpg')

for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (9,6),None)
    print(ret)

    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)

        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)

        # Draw and display the corners
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (9,6), corners2,ret)
        cv2.imshow('img',img)
        cv2.waitKey(500)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)
```

Comment: Well it says "'gray' is not defined". check gray image right before calibrateCamera to see if it's a valid image.

Answer (score 0):

You load the images inside the for loop and `gray` is defined only there. You then reference it outside of the loop in the last line to get the image dimensions but `gray` is out of scope.

Creating a variable holding the dimensions of the image before the for loop and filling it inside the loop should do the trick.

```
dims = None

for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    dims = img.shape[::-1]

(...)

ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, dims, None, None)
```